# Two equivalent formulas of predicate logic.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I need to find two equivalent formulas of predicate logic F,G s.t in one of them we only have free variables and in the other one we have exactly two quantifiers.

I have the following but this just seems too banal and cheap to me.

$\forall x \neg P(z)$

$\forall x \exists y \neg P(z)$

please help me understand this better as I am stuck. Furthermore, what should I read more to understand this better?

Comment: You want one of your formulas to have only free variables, but both of your formulas have at least one bound variable.  Replace the first of your two formulas by $\neg P(z)$, and you'll have what you want.

Comment: i thought a variable was free if the variable in the quantifier was different? have i understood the definition wrong? Thanks for the reply

Comment: The $z$ is free in your formulas, but the $x$ in both formulas and the $y$ in the second are bound.

Comment: Ok thanks now its clear

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the formula $P$ already has *only* free variables (that is, it is true that all of its (zero) free variables are free). So, you could even do:

$P$

And

$\forall x \forall y \ P$